# Does google sheets api v4 support "Google Application Default Crentials"?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am using "Google Application Default Credentials" in my scala application to talk to the google sheets api. However, I am getting a "PERMISSION_DENIED" error message from the api response.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
private val client: Sheets = {
    val serviceAccountScopes = List(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY)

    // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials
    val credential: GoogleCredential = GoogleCredential
      .getApplicationDefault()
      .createScoped(serviceAccountScopes.asJava)

    new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
      .setApplicationName(applicationName)
      .build()
  }

val response = client.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadSheetId, "Total Cost!A2:C2").execute()

val values = response.getValues
```

Here is the error message:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
>   Forbidden {   "code" : 403,   "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
>       "reason" : "forbidden"   } ],   "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",   "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
>   }

I did enabled google sheet api in the google developer console, and the sheet I am trying to read is under my google drive.

The only thing I am not sure about is the google sheet api doc https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing does not mention anything about if the api supports "Google Application Default Credentials" or not.

Anything I might miss or did wrong here?

Comment: It should support that use case. Can you make sure the service account has access to that spreadsheet?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I have just posted a similar question with a bit more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886522/use-application-default-credentials-on-google-compute-engine-to-access-sheets-ap

Comment: Seems like Google Sheet API related scopes (i.e. not Google Cloud scopes) are not supported by Google Application Default Credentials.