# Use Application Default Credentials on Google Compute Engine to access Sheets API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-sheets-api, google-authentication

Does the ADC (Application Default Credentials) workflow only support Google Cloud APIs (for example, supports for Google Cloud Storage API, but not the Google Sheet API)?

I'm referring to [google.auth's default method](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default) - not having to store any private keys with the code is a great win and the main benefit of making effective use of the ADC (Application Default Credentials) setup.

The following code works if I set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environmental variable to the private key file, say key.json.  This is inline with the `default` method as per step 1 of the `google.auth` package:  `1. If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set to the path of a valid service account JSON private key file, then it is loaded and returned.`

```
import google.auth
from apiclient import discovery

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'])

sheets = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

SPREADSHEETID = '....'

result = sheets.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEETID, range='Sheet1!A:B').execute()

print result.get('values', [])
```

Now, looking at step 4 of the method: `4. If the application is running in Compute Engine or the App Engine flexible environment then the credentials and project ID are obtained from the Metadata Service.`

If i remove the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environmental variable on a Google Compute instance, I get the following error:

`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/..../values/Sheet1%21A%3AB?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">`

This is not consistent with Google's wizard as per the Cloud Console:
[image: find out what credentials you need]

[image: you don't need any credentials]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing), the scope that you're using requires [Oauth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) authorization. Therefore, a user login and consent is required.

Comment: Thank you this is useful.  The above wizard is therefore misleading.  The ``default`` method (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/auth/_default.py#L293):
1 - First checks for the ``GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`` variable (explicit)
2 - then for SDK credentials
3 - then for Google App Engine ones
4 - and then only for GCE which simply returns compute_engine.Credentials() (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py#L35)

Comment: It works when the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is present and pointing to the standard json key with the following attributes: type, project_id, private_key_id, private_key, client_email, client_id, auth_uri, token_uri, auth_provider_x509_cert_url, client_x509_cert_url.

Comment: with with 2,3 and 4 it only sees the credentials which have the following attributes: client_id, client_secret, refresh_token, type.  It is therefore unable to perform an Oauth 2.0 authorization.

Comment: Yes, I understand that's happening in the `for checker` loop

Answer (score 4):

Credentials are optional for the build constructor.  Omit them and the Cloud Function service account will be used to authenticate against the Sheet.

```
from apiclient import discovery

sheets = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4')

SPREADSHEETID = '....'

result = sheets.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEETID, range='Sheet1!A:B').execute()

print result.get('values', [])
```

Comment: Fantastic! This works locally too if you set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. Why do the official docs recommend thirty lines of code with pickling tokens and stuff, if this is so simple and works in any environment?